# I have a error with my query

Tags: sql, vb.net

```
sql = "select * from studentlist where firstname like '%" & Transaction.SEARCHSTUDENT.Text & "%' or studentnum like '%" & Transaction.SEARCHSTUDENT.Text & "%' exists(select * from studentlist where status = 'Vacant')"
```

help me fix my query pls

Comment: What's the error? Have you tried executing it manually?

Answer (score 4):

***Please consider using parameter binding instead of concatenating your parameters directly in the SQL string.***

That said, you have a typo:

```
"%' exists(...
```

should be (notice the missing `and`):

```
"%' and exists(
```